# How to make a bootable partition from scratch?

Tags: startup, efi, kernel, darwin

What I want to achieve is to make a new bootable partition on my MacBook's SSD, so it should be possible to press `Option` key on startup and choose this partition to boot from.

Why do I need that? I just successfully compiled XNU kernel from sources, found some drivers (kernel extensions), so now I want to boot this kernel and to load `bash` after boot process finishes. The key idea is to make a minimal Mac OS, just with command line interface.

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
Alexanders-MacBook-Pro:~ aperechnev$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     99.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.8 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.5 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.9 GB    disk1s5
```

What I want to achieve first is to see the new partition as an option to boot from by pressing `Option` key and to get some error when I try to boot from that partition.

Comment: What file system will this operating system be using? APFS, JHFS+ or something else?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm open to any file system, even to FAT if it's easier to make it bootable.

Comment: You say you want a "new bootable partition", but you do not say how you want the partition formatted. If you want APFS then you could just create a new volume the existing APFS container. If you want JHFS+, then you would need to shrink the existing APFS container and create a new partition in the resulting free space. Either is easily achieved, but the commands are completely different.

Comment: @DavidAnderson this is how a usual partitions are creating, not bootable. The question is how to make a _bootable_ partition.

Comment: You don't make a partition bootable really - that is a legacy method for MBR disks.  You need a .efi executable bootloader on a volume formatted with a filesystem the firmware can see (FAT, HFS or APFS).  macOS puts `boot.efi` in the `Macintosh HD/System/Library/CoreServices` and `Preboot/{some GUID}/System/Library/CoreServices` directories - either of which will boot macOS.  So question - do you have a `boot.efi` and if so where?

Comment: [cont]..You can check [Booting the Mac: loading boot.efi and Secure Boot](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/08/10/booting-the-mac-loading-boot-efi-and-secure-boot/) and the [Kernel Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/booting/booting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-SW2-BAJJBJEG) for more info on `boot.efi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes it bootable? This has change slightly over time. I will assume you are not going to use encryption. Below are some basic examples. This is not a complete list.

1. The original OS X operating system.

   - The partition should be type `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.
   - The partition should be `JHFS+` formatted. If you are using the Disk Utility, you would select `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`.
   - The boot file `boot.efi` needs to be in the `System/Library/CoreServices` folder.
   - There used to be a requirement that a file named `mach_kernal` exist in the root folder. The file can be empty.
2. The macOS operating system stored in an APFS volume. This became available starting with High Sierra. This volume resides in a APFS container. The container can be comprised of a single APFS partition or two APFS partitions on separate drives.

   - The partition(s) should be type `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.
   - The container should be `APFS` formatted. If you are using the Disk Utility, you would select `APFS`.
   - The boot file `boot.efi` needs to be in the `System/Library/CoreServices` folder in a APFS volume with no specific role.
   - The `mach_kernal` file can be omitted.
3. A generic operating system stored in a FAT or ExFAT formatted volume. This works on Macs where High Sierra or a newer version of macOS has been installed.

   - The partition(s) should be type `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7`.
   - The container should be `FAT32` or `ExFAT` formatted. If you are using the Disk Utility, you would select `MS-DOS (FAT)` or `ExFAT`.
   - The boot file `BOOTX64.EFI` needs to be in the `EFI/BOOT` folder.
4. Operating system stored in partitions not recognized by the firmware. For example, partitions with NTFS (Windows) or EXT4 (Linux) volumes. Basically, the boot files go in a small EFI partition. The boot files are responsible for transferring control to the partition(s) containing the operating system.

   - The partition(s) should be type `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`.
   - The container should be `FAT32` formatted. If you are using the Disk Utility, you would select `MS-DOS (FAT)`.
   - The boot file `BOOTX64.EFI` needs to be in the `EFI/BOOT` folder.