# Repairing an unbootable BootCamp partition

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I primarily use Windows on my MacBook Pro, so my OS X partition goes quite a while between updates.  After upgrading to Catalina, I no longer see my Windows partition when I hold `option`

I can see the "Bootacamp" partition in finder, the disk just doesn't show up when I try to boot from it.  I have BootChamp installed, and it provides this error message when attempting to set the startup disk:

[image]

Taking a look at this question [How to make a bootable partition from scratch?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378595/how-to-make-a-bootable-partition-from-scratch#378633)

It says that there must be an EFI/Boot folder on the Windows disk. There is not.  I did create a Windows Boot disk using the BootCamp utility, and attempted to copy the files over. I can't copy the files over because the partition is read only.

Comment: macOS can't write to the Windows partition once it's formatted as NTFS (Windows NT File System).

Comment: @Todd: The `EFI/Boot` folder in not in a NTFS formatted volume. This folder resides in the EFI partition which is FAT32 formatted.

Comment: @DavidAnderson sorry I misunderstood the question. Yes, you are right. The EFI partition is not NTFS formatted.

Comment: @Brian by Windows boot disk, do you mean an installer or a ready bootable version of Windows?

Comment: @Todd: The OP opened the Boot Camp Assistant and made the selection shown in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/1EDoEgz).  This would be an installer. Anyway, read the question. BootChamp is some third party application the OP downloaded from the internet. Catalina uses SIP, which would prohibit the `bless` command from changing the startup disk.